# Array in a select query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following:

```
<?php

    $array = join(',', $ids); // this prints 3,4,6,7,8

    $stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN (?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $array);
    $stmt->execute();

?>
```

However, when I have it print the results, it only shows the comments from the first id (`3`) and not the others. What's wrong?

Comment: Each element in an `IN` clause is a separate element, not one giant string

Comment: You're passing a string into the query, but telling the query to expect an integer (the `i` in `bind_param()`).  Change the `i` to `s` and it should work.

Comment: @jedwards Didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayCount = count($ids);
$binders = array_fill(0, $arrayCount, '?');

// Create an array of references to the values we want to bind
$bindValues = array(); 
foreach($ids as $key => $id) 
    $bindValues[$keys] = &$ids[$key]; 

// Build SQL statement with the necessary number of bind placeholders
$stmt = $cxn->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $binders) . ')'
);
// Bind each value (has to be done by reference)
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), $bindValues));
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe for this to work as intended, you have to directly substitute the values into the string:

```
$idString = '';
foreach($ids as $id) {
 $idString .= $id . ',';
}
$idString = substr($idString, 0, -1);
$stmt = $cxn->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN (".$idstring.")");
$stmt->execute();
```

Unfortunately, this can then open you up to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Any way to do this while avoiding vulnerabilities?

Comment: @Bagwell, sure, the easy way would be to validate / escape `$ids` -- a more complex method would be to build the string you pass to prepare after you know the length of `$ids`, and include that many `?` symbols, and then build the `bind_param()` function arguments accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Bind them to a string.

```
$idString = '';
foreach($ids as $id) {
 $idString .= $id . ',';
}
$idString = substr($idString, 0, -1);
$stmt = $cxn->prepare('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN (?)');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $idString);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Because it shouldn't work.... You're creating string containing "3,4,6,7,8" and trying to bind it as an integer

Comment: Hah. You could have just pointed that out rather than beating around the bush.

Comment: So now you're effectively executing `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN ('3,4,6,7,8')`